# Simple docker-compose.yml not mounting volumes. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm a docker newbie and I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for a few hours already.

I have a simple docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - .:/rails
      - ruby-bundle-cache:/bundle
    build: .
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
    networks:
      - net1
    command: /bin/bash -c "rm -f /tmp/server.pid && RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV} bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -P /tmp/server.pid"

volumes:
  ruby-bundle-cache:
      external: true

networks:
  net1:
    driver: bridge
```

When I try setting stuff up with `docker compose up --build` I get the following output

```
% RAILS_ENV=development docker compose up --build
[+] Building 0.7s (8/8) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 69B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for ghcr.io/rails/cli:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.4s
 => [1/5] FROM ghcr.io/rails/cli:latest@sha256:b2b68e687e98db836bfe81c01e346bd27370e80f89d1e2c5b5dae93d519677c2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /rails                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN bundle install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 > [5/5] RUN bundle install:
#0 0.273 Could not locate Gemfile
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bundle install]: exit code: 10
```

Needless to say, the Gemfile exists, and when I run an interactive shell on the container ghcr.io/rails/cli:latest and execute the same `bundle install` command everything works just fine. For some reason, the command fails in docker compose flow.

my `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM ghcr.io/rails/cli:latest

WORKDIR /rails
VOLUME /bundle

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
RUN bundle install
```

both files exist in the same directory as the command is invoked from

I tried pruning all the images, deleting caches, trying this on Linux and other computers with no prior docker installation on them, etc. Nothing works. It suggests there is some fundamental misunderstanding on my behalf of how the docker volumes work?

Please advise

Comment: Volumes are a runtime construct, for the running containers, they aren't applied to the build. Any volumes defined for the build are done in the Dockerfile and the source is not defined for them (the result of those is not what you're looking for).